# Let $\alpha=(714)(3925)\in S_9$. Find $\beta \in S_9$ such that $\beta^5=\alpha$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

> I have the following question:
> Let $\alpha=(714)(3925)\in S_9.$ Find $\beta \in S_9$ such that $\beta^5=\alpha$.

I know that $o(\alpha)=12$.

I do have the answer, yet I don't understand the way, I tried to "play" with $\beta$ and $\alpha$ since we know that $\alpha=\alpha^{13}$ yet were unsuccessful with achieving result.

Any ideas? (If you could please go to detail so I understand how to approach to such questions I'll be grateful).

Thank you!

Comment: you might find it helpful to look at the powers of $(7,1,4)$ and $(3,9,2,5)$

Comment: Note that $5\cdot 5\equiv 1 \bmod 12$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: $\alpha^{12}=1$ so that $\alpha=\alpha ^{13}=\alpha^{25}=\alpha^{37}=\dots $

Now can you spot a fifth power?

And can you see how you would generalise this?

Comment: Fifth power is $61$, generalise maybe $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ so that $12k+1$?

Comment: @JaVaPG Note $(\alpha^5)^5$. If $\alpha^r=1$ then $\alpha$ is an $q$-th power if you can solve $nr+1=mq$ because then $\alpha=\alpha^{nr+1}=\alpha^{mq}$. This can be done, if it is possible, using Euclid's algorithm. If $r$ is the order of $\alpha$ then this can be done iff $p$ is coprime to $r$.

Comment: I'm still not sure about it this is what I did : $\beta^5=\alpha \rightarrow \beta^5=(\alpha^5)^5 \rightarrow \beta^5=(\alpha^{12})^2*\alpha$ so I managed to reach $\alpha^{nr+1}$ yet I don't really understand what I suppose to now, why did you choose $(\alpha^5)^5$

Comment: @JaVaPG Suppose $\beta = \alpha^5$, you then have $\alpha=\alpha^{25}=\beta^5$

Comment: How did you know to suppose $\beta = \alpha^5$? We are looking for $\beta^5=\alpha$

Comment: @JaVaPG I was looking for $\alpha=\alpha^{12k+1}$ with $12k+1=5m$. I then put $\beta=\alpha^m$